# How to specify action button template in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

tell me pls. Why if I specify a action button template, the button is displayed regardless of the access rights?

```
$listMapper
    ->add('_action', 'actions', [
        'actions' => [
            //displayed depending on the access rights
            'edit' => [],
            //displayed regardless of access rights 
            'delete' => [
                'template' => '@App/list__action_delete.html.twig',                 
            ],
        ]
    ]);
```

And how to specify a template so that the button is displayed depending on the access rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probable reason is that you've forgot to add access check into your custom template.

If you look into [build-in Sonata template](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/src/Resources/views/CRUD/list__action_delete.html.twig#L12) you'll see that actual access check is done in template themselves not in outer code. So just copy those check from original template into yours.

Example:

```
    {% if admin.hasAccess('delete', object) and admin.hasRoute('delete') %}
        {# --- Your custom button view here --- #}
    {% endif %}
```